# Count of number of users who have downloaded/viewed a GitHub repo

Tags: github

Is there a way within GitHub to see at the very least the overall number of users who have either seen or downloaded a repository?

Comment: Related (on SO) [Github: Can I see the number of downloads for a repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338358/github-can-i-see-the-number-of-downloads-for-a-repo)

Comment: Also [How to see count of project downloads on GitHub?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198194/how-to-see-count-of-project-downloads-on-github)

Answer (score 2):

Neither of those stats is available, at least not through the [Github API](http://developer.github.com/). According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4339085/875067) on Stack Overflow, you can only see whether it has been downloaded or not.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub API returns downloads count of binary file releases. I developed a [little script](http://mmilidoni.github.io/github-downloads-count/) to easly get downloads count by command line.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, you can get information about your [Releases via the API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/). However, the `download_count` value does not track users, just downloads.

---

For those using WordPress, I developed this plugin: [**GitHub Release Downloads**](https://ivanrf.com/en/github-release-downloads/). It allows you to get the download count, links and more information for releases of GitHub repositories.

To address the original question, the shortcode `[grd_count user="User" repo="MyRepo"]` will return the number of downloads for a repository. This number corresponds to the sum of all download count values of all releases for one GitHub repository.

Example:

[image: Example]